# Simulink : Variables in PID Controller

Tags: performance, simulink, workspace, pid-controller

I want to set the coefficient of my PID controller (P, I and D) as variables.

I want P, I and D coming from the 3 inports 2, 3 and 4 as represented in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACo8L.png)

I tried to create P, I and D variables in the workspace. The PID block can read it (the error in the picture is due to I removed them from the workspace later).

However, how can I link the inports to the P, I and D variables and to update continuously the coefficients of the PID ? What block should I used ?

I would prefer not using a matlab script.

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Rémi.

Answer (score 0):

Change the PID block from "internal" to "external" - you can see this in your screenshot under the "source" menu - this will turn the P,I and D terms into inputs to your PID block, that you can then wire to the submodule inputs